# Toolbar Image update when rotating

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I have a `Xamarin` Forms App where I set the `Toolbar` through an xml file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/customToolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/toolbarImage" 
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And set it in the OnCreate method of the MainActivity with

```
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.CustomToolbar;
```

The `ImageView` doesn't have a source attribute because the image itself is received as base64 string from the server. To add the picture to the `Toolbar` I used the `OnStart` method

```
ImageView toolbarImg = this.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.toolbarImage);
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imgAsBase64))
            {
                    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgAsBase64);
                    Android.Graphics.Bitmap decodedByte = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    toolbarImg.SetImageBitmap(decodedByte);

            }
```

So far this is working, but when I changed the orientation the image disappeared.

What I have tried was to add the Image in `OnConfigurationChanged` again but that didn't changed anything.

Also setting the Image of the `ImageView` to null before assigning the new picture, `Invalidate()`, `PostInvalidate()`, `RequestLayout()` also didn't help. Still when I change the orientation no Image is shown.

Would appreciate some help on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you can stop changing the orientation to avoid this problem.  Second you can judge in `OnConfigurationChanged` method when the screen has changed its orientation and do something. Please make sure the `imgAsBase64` is right, because the `Activity` will be created again when the screen rotating, and anything will be created again. [This is the abnormal life cycle of the Activity.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes.html)

Comment: I need orientation in my app so that isn't a solution. The Image is right, otherwise it wouldn't be showed the first time I start. My approaches in OnConfigurationChanged didn't helped as mentioned in my post

Comment: I mean that that your activity will be `recreated` when your screen rotating, and everything will be re-load. Please see the [`onSaveInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [`onRestoreInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) method.

Comment: The [`OnConfigurationChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) method will not be called if you haven't set the configChanges attribute in your manifest. Please look at the document.

Comment: There is a solution, move your code from `OnConfigurationChanged` to `OnSaveInstanceState`, and set the image source in your `OnRestoreInstanceState`

Comment: I have `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize` defined in my MainActivity. I can't really use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` as this takes about 2 minutes to reload the camera :/

Comment: So, you mean the `byte[]` is right, but it can't be used to your `ImageView`, and the `OnConfigurationChanged` method is not helpful?

Comment: The `byte[]` is correct 100%. And I also can use it in ImageView. My only problem is, that when I rotate the device the Image disappear even thou I explicit set again the picture in `OnConfigurationChanged`

Comment: Still didn't find any solution :/ Does someone has an idea?

Comment: Can you give me a demo which will reproduce your problem?

Comment: Pretty simple demo with nothing in it except the toolbar :D just rotate the device. Problem also occurs with an emulator https://www.file-upload.net/download-12892114/ToolbarTestApp.zip.html

Comment: It's not a .zip file, it is a .exe file,bro. I need .zip file which include your application code that can reproduce your problem, thanks!

Comment: Mh you probably clicked on the ad :D I uploaded it to GitHub https://github.com/AndiAn94/ToolbarTest Happy new year

Comment: Hi, I have update my answer, please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1) Remove `|ConfigChanges.Orientation` from `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize|ConfigChanges.Orientation`, that mean your activity will recreate when your screen rotate.

2) Add below code in your `OnConfigurationChanged` method, above the `SetImageToToolbar();` method, like this:

```
    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.CustomToolbar;
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, null);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        SetImageToToolbar();
    }
```

### Why should you add these code?

I think there is something wrong in the `imgView` in your code when screen rotating, so I think the codes in `OnCreate()` method will help it.

### Update:

There is something wrong in the second solution, if you have many pages, it will go wrong, so I provide another solution, use custom `NavigationPageRenderer`:

1) Add `MyNavigationPage` in your pcl:

```
namespace ToolbarTestApp
{
    class MyNavigationPage:NavigationPage
    {
        public MyNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root) {
        }
    }
}
```

2) Replace `MainPage = new MyNavigationPage(new TestPage());` with `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TestPage());`

3)Add `MyNavigationPageRender` in your android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyNavigationPage), typeof(MyNavigationPageRender))]
namespace ToolbarTestApp.Droid
{
    class MyNavigationPageRender : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public MyNavigationPageRender(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            (Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as MainActivity).SetImageToToolbar();
        }
    }
}
```

Change your `SetImageToToolbar` method to public, and you needn't override `OnConfigurationChanged` method, just remove it.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Didn't have the time to try it yet, but as soon as i tried I will accept the answer (: Thanks

Comment: Just tried it out and worked perfectly :) Thanks for your answer